# Dynamically adjust left position of sliding menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a web site that uses a sliding menu. By default is sets left to -370px. This shows only the "MENU" text on the screen (see pictures below). When a user mouses over the menu it expands to the right and allows the user to select a menu item. If the user expands one of the items to show sub items, the menu grows as necessary. The issue is when the menu slides back in to the left. I would like the menu to ONLY show "MENU" regardless of the length of the text of the menu items. It works out to only showing the right 31px of the menu.

[image: Current Menu display]

```css
#navigation_slideout ul li.expanding{
 height: auto 
}

.expanding  label{
 /*background-color: #AAAFAB;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: white;
 */
 padding: 3px;
 padding-left: 25px;
}

#navigation_slideout ul li ul li a.expanding1 { 

 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 height: auto ;
}

.expanding li > ul { 
 left:-35px;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
}

.expanding input[type=checkbox] { 
 display: none; 
}

.expanding input[type=checkbox] ~ ul { 
 max-height: 0;
 max-width: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space:nowrap;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;  
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease;  
    -o-transition:all 1s ease;  
    transition:all 1s ease; 
}

.expanding input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul { 
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 opacity: 1;
}

.expanding input[type=checkbox] + label:before{
 transform-origin:25% 50%;
   border: 8px solid transparent;
   border-width: 8px 12px; 
   border-left-color: white;
   margin-left: -20px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 content: '';
 color: #AAAFAB;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease;  
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease;  
    -o-transition:all .5s ease;  
    transition:all .5s ease; 
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 1px;
}

.expanding input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 /*margin-top: 6px;
   margin-left: -25px;*/
}
#navigation_slideout {
 position: fixed;
 top: 85px;
 left: -370px;
 -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
 -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
 -o-transition-duration: .5s;
 transition-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
 box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
}

 #navigation_slideout:hover {
  left: -39px;
}

#navigation_slideout ul
 {
 list-style: none;
 }

#navigation_slideout ul li {
 background: #548EBE;
 width: auto;
 min-width:325px;
 /*height: 30px;*/
 height: auto;
 text-align: left;
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-family:HelveticaNeue,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 12pt;
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;

}
#navigation_slideout ul li a{
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight:bold;
 display: block;
 background-color:#548EBE;
 color:white;
}
#navigation_slideout ul li ul{ 


}

#navigation_slideout ul li ul li { 

width:10px;
position:relative;
left:-41px;
}


#navigation_slideout ul li ul li a { 
background:#548EBE;
width:326px;
height:30px;
text-align:left;
padding-top:5px;
font-family:  helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12pt;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
}

#menu{
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
 transform: rotate(-90deg); 
 font-family:HelveticaNeue,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14pt;
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 right:0px;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 0px

}

#menu a{
  font-size: 14pt;
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-decoration:none;
}

table.nospacing { 
border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;


} 
table.nospacing th, td {
 padding: 0;
  }
  .menu-col{max-width: 30px;}
```

```html
<div id="navigation_slideout" style="background-color:#548EBE;z-index:1"  onclick="">
  <table class="nospacing" style="border-style:none">
    <tr>
      <td style="border-style:solid">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="default_copy(1).html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about/about.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact/contacts.html" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contacts</a></li>           </ul>
  <hr width="200px">
  <ul style="position:relative">
          <li class="expanding"><input class="expanding" type="checkbox" id="cb1"><label class="expanding" for="cb1">Transitioning A Subject</label>
           <ul class="expanding">
              <li class="expanding1"><a class="expanding1" href="#" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Overview - Transitioning a Subject</a></li>
              <li class="expanding1"><a class="expanding1" href="#" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pick A Topic Area</a></li>
              <li class="expanding1"><a class="expanding1" href="#" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Design Topic Area</a></li>
              <li class="expanding1"><a class="expanding1" href="#" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Set Up Config Mgmt</a></li>
              <li class="expanding1"><a class="expanding1" href="#" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Develop Topic Area</a></li>
              <li class="expanding1"><a class="expanding1" href="#" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Review Topic Area</a></li>
              <li class="expanding1"><a class="expanding1" href="#" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Publish Topic Area</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="expanding"><input class="expanding" type="checkbox" id="cb2"><label class="expanding" for="cb2">Developing the Topic Area</label></li>
          <li class="expanding"><input class="expanding" type="checkbox" id="cb3"><label class="expanding" for="cb3">Useful HTML Techniques</label></li>
          <li class="expanding"><input class="expanding" type="checkbox" id="cb4"><label class="expanding" for="cb4">Best Practice Examples</label></li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td   class="menu-col" style="border-left:medium;border-left-color:white;border-left-style:solid">
      <p id="menu"><a href="#" onclick=";return false;">MENU</a></p>
  </td>

    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you wanna fix the width?

Comment: I don't want a fixed width. I had that originally but that led to issues with long menu items. I would like to be able to set how much of the menu is displayed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/ru9joppk/2/

**Javascript:**

```
function width(){
var width = document.getElementById("navigation_slideout").offsetWidth;
var offsetWidth = width - (width + width - 35);
document.getElementById('navigation_slideout').style.width = width + "px";
document.getElementById('navigation_slideout').style.left = offsetWidth + "px";
}
```

**CSS**

```
 #navigation_slideout:hover {
  left: -39px !important;
}
```

Comment: Not quite. If you look at your code you made the long item (Transitioning A Subject Transitioning A Subject Transitioning A Subject) at the main level. If you change that to one of the lower levels (Overview - Transitioning a Subject Overview - Transitioning a Subject Overview - Transitioning a Subject) it does not work.

Comment: @FlyFish I don't feel like coding the whole thing for you, try what I gave you modify it as needed then come back when you have another question. There are too many variables to code the whole thing here and now.